# Download multiple files in parallel with wget

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, wget

I want to check a URL list and if the file ( .pdf) exists, download it. I use this command and it's working;

```
for i in `cat url.txt`; do if wget -q --method=HEAD $i; then wget $i; fi ; done
```

But this is really slow, I have a lot of URLs to check.
Is there a way to "multithread" this command?

Comment: This is not about downloading multiple files in parallel (as mentionned with the review), it's more about to check all the URLs in parallel

Comment: Perhaps you can put the downloads in background. Do that by replacing `then wget $i;`  with `then exec wget $i 2>&1 &;`.

Comment: Just remembered about [`aria2c`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html). It has options to read URLs from a file and download multiple files in parallel.

Comment: Thanks but I have to check if the file exists first (with the option --method=HEAD), if not it's going to download an empty .pdf

Comment: My first comment takes care of that so. Bear in mind that if you have tons of files in the list you will end up with tons of parallel downloads in background. I guess you need to control how many URL you test per step.

Comment: I'm testing your first comment to see if it's faster ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228015/discussion-between-ciwol-and-accdias).

Comment: Just a word of caution: you don't want to hit the web server too aggressively. It makes sense to optimize this code, but if you overdo it and it's all coming from the same web server, you might get yourself blocked.

Comment: @joanis You're right. But I'm looking for only 1 file automatically generated on this server, with a pretty much random name. I'm just trying the names (numbers based on timestamp) to try to find it !

Comment: Hum, that might get you blocked too, if they think you're trying to guess what is intended as a randomly-generated privacy token in the file name...

Comment: But, you could automate a bit less like this: `cat url.txt | xargs wget --method=HEAD` and look for "200 OK" in the output. You should get "404 Not Found" for each bad URL, and "200 OK" only for the good one. But this solution amplified my concern even more about getting blocked by the server. This way this is faster is that you're not launching a new `wget` process for each URL. But it's less automated because you'll have to save and parse the logs instead of relying on the exit status.

Comment: I'm trying to use xargs as you mentioned, can't get it working with the "if" statement.
I know you're right about getting blocked, I don't see any other solution, and if blocked, I'll let it go.

Comment: Just saw this comment, quite a bit later... anyway, my `xargs` solution is instead of your `if` statement, and you would have to save the output to a file and scan the logs for "200 OK". That has the significant disadvantage that it won't stop when you find the right URL, though.

Comment: You can use GNU Parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Use perl parallel

e.g.

```
for i in `cat url.txt`; do if wget -q --method=HEAD $i; then 
   echo "wget '$i'"; fi ; done \
   | parallel
```